# Latex: Get text of hypertarget

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Please take a look at the following LaTeX code. How can I get the text of a `\hypertarget`?

```
\newcounter{reqCounter}
\newcommand{\newReq}[1]{\stepcounter{reqCounter}\hypertarget{#1}{(R\arabic{reqCounter})}}
\newcommand{\Req}[1]{(\hyperlink{#1}{%text of hypertarget%})}
```

Example:

```
This is a requirement \newReq{req1}. This is the same requirement as \Req{req1}.
```

Result:

> This is a requirement (R1). This is the same requirement as (R1).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use the regular `\label`-`\ref` system in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{reqCounter}\renewcommand{\thereqCounter}{R\arabic{reqCounter}}
\newcommand{\newReq}[1]{\refstepcounter{reqCounter}\label{#1}(\thereqCounter)}
\newcommand{\Req}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\begin{document}
Example: This is a requirement~\newReq{req1}. This is the same requirement as~\Req{req1}.
\end{document}
```

Depending on the use case, there may be more optimal ways of dealing with this.

Comment: And where can I find documentation on more optimal ways? I'm about desperate enough to ask a new question ...